# $http.get not executing functions on success

Tags: angularjs, function, http, ionic-framework

I am doing my first Angular project (ionic framework) where i have to get some data from database and on success I havet  to

1. store it in a variable
2. navigate to a page where this variable is used.

The page is navigating, but data are not sent.

Here is my **search.html** code:

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="ListCtrl">
<ion-pane>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Real Estate</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
        <h4 align="center"> Enter Place or Pincode </h4>
        <div class="list list-inset" >
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" name="place" ng-model="data.place" value="" placeholder="Place"  ng-focus="$scope.placefocus=true;data.pincode=null" ng-blur="$scope.placefocus=false" ng-disabled = "$scope.pincodefocus">
           </label>
           <label class="item item-input">
               <input type="number" name="pincode" ng-model="data.pincode" value="" placeholder="Pin Code" ng-focus="$scope.pincodefocus=true;data.place=null" ng-blur="$scope.pincodefocus=false" ng-disabled="$scope.placefocus">
           </label>
       </div>
       <button class="button button-block button-positive"  ng-click="getdata()">
           Search
       </button>
   </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
</body>
```

And here is my **controller** code :

```
app.controller('ListCtrl',function($scope,$http,$location,$window){
$scope.data = {};
$scope.getdata = function(){
    //alert($scope.data.place);
    $http.get("http://localhost/angular/data.php")  
                                                      //,{'place':$scope.data.place,'pincode':$scope.data.pincode})
        .success(function(response,status,headers,config){
            alert(response);
            $scope.datas=response;
            $scope.navig('/show.html');
        })
}
$scope.navig = function(url){
    $window.location.href=url;
};
});
```

and here is my **show.html** page :

```
<ion-content>
<div class="list card" ng-repeat="site in datas">
<div class="item item-body">
    <a href="#" class="subdued"><img class="full-image" src="img/{{site.image}}" height="150px">
        <p>
            RS.{{site.price}} &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <span> {{site.square_feet}} sq.ft &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</span><span>{{site.bed}} BHK</span>
        </p>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

`alert(response)` in the controller code alerts `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`
But the output page (show.html) is blank

If I call `navig("/show.html")` directly from the button click (in search.html) instead of `getdata()` and change the controller code to the below one, I am getting the result: (But I cannot execute this way because I have to get data from database for particular place and pincode entered)

```
app.controller('ListCtrl',function($scope,$http,$location,$window){
    $scope.data = {};
    $http.get("http://localhost/angular/data.php")
                                                  //,{'place':$scope.data.place,'pincode':$scope.data.pincode})
        .success(function(response,status,headers,config){
            alert(response);
            $scope.datas=response;
        })
    $scope.navig = function(url){
        $window.location.href=url;
    };
});
```

Comment: It would had been great if you had shared a fiddle on which we can edit.
Anyways, try using $scope.$apply() after setting response. It might help

Comment: How can I use $scope.$apply() Please give a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the success function, use the `.then()` function.The code below is from the angular documentation.

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Here is the text from the [Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

> **Deprecation Notice**
>
> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been
>   deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If
>   $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these
>   methods will throw $http/legacy error.

Comment: If I use .then instead of .success, I get "TypeError: $http.get(...).then(...).error is not a function" in google chrome console.

Answer (score 0):

$scope works with in controller only! Instead of $scope use $rootScope.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the promise.
Why don't you try this.

```
 app.controller('ListCtrl',function($scope,$http,$location,$window){
        $scope.data = {};
        $http.get("http://localhost/angular/data.php")
                                                      //,{'place':$scope.data.place,'pincode':$scope.data.pincode})
            .then(function(response){
                alert(response);
                $scope.datas=response;
            })
        $scope.navig = function(url){
            $window.location.href=url;
        };
    });
```